# What is the correct way to restart a Dask Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: dask, dask-distributed, dask-kubernetes

I have a web service which makes use of a [dask-kubernetes](https://kubernetes.dask.org/en/latest/) cluster. The web service is long-living, and for safety, I would like to cycle the Dask kubernetes cluster every *n* days.

There are two possibilities to do this.

1. Use `dask.distributed.Client.restart()`.
2. Use `KubeCluster.close()`, followed by a re-initialization of the KubeCluster.

What is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no single correct way.  Do whatever feels best for you.

You might also want to look at the `--lifetime` keywords on dask-worker.